# Set xticks, yticks and colorbar tikz at once

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I couldn't figure it out how I can manually set the xticks, yticks as well as those ticks of the colorbar *at once*. It only works for one of those three, but compiling never ends if I try to change a second tick property. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% TikZ Packages
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,xlabel near ticks,ylabel near ticks,}
\tikzset{font=\footnotesize}

\usepackage{fp}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots,colormaps}
\usepackage[tightpage,active,pdftex,floats,graphics]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter
\def\customrevertcolormap#1{%
\pgfplotsarraycopy{pgfpl@cm@#1}\to{custom@COPY}%
\c@pgf@counta=0
\c@pgf@countb=\pgfplotsarraysizeof{custom@COPY}\relax
\c@pgf@countd=\c@pgf@countb
\advance\c@pgf@countd by-1 %
\pgfutil@loop
\ifnum\c@pgf@counta<\c@pgf@countb
    \pgfplotsarrayselect{\c@pgf@counta}\of{custom@COPY}\to\pgfplots@loc@TMPa
    \pgfplotsarrayletentry\c@pgf@countd\of{pgfpl@cm@#1}=\pgfplots@loc@TMPa
    \advance\c@pgf@counta by1 %
    \advance\c@pgf@countd by-1 %
  \pgfutil@repeat
 %\pgfplots@colormap@showdebuginfofor{#1}%
 }%

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
   colormap/jet,
}
\pagestyle{empty}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
 \customrevertcolormap{jet}
 \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},%
 %      colorbar,%
 %      colorbar style={ %[colorbar sampled,colorbar style={samples=8}]
 %                  %ytick={0,20,...,100},
 %          ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
 %          yticklabels={
 %                  \textsf{0},
 %                  \textsf{20},
 %                  \textsf{40},
 %                  \textsf{60},
 %                  \textsf{80},
 %                  \textsf{100}
 %                  }
 %      }
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    xticklabels={
        \textsf{0.1},
        \textsf{0.2},
        \textsf{0.3},
        \textsf{0.4},
        \textsf{0.5},
        \textsf{0.6}
    }
 %      ytick={5,10,15},
 %      yticklabels={
 %          \textsf{0.2},
 %          \textsf{0.5},
 %          \textsf{1.0}
 %      }
    ]
 \addplot3 
    [surf,
    shader=flat corner,
    mesh/rows=15,
    point meta=z,%
    ]
 coordinates {
 (1,1,97.80) (2,1,99.40) (3,1,100.00) (4,1,99.70) (5,1,100.00) (6,1,100.00) 
 (1,2,93.50) (2,2,98.10) (3,2,99.00) (4,2,99.60) (5,2,99.90) (6,2,100.00) 
 (1,3,81.80) (2,3,94.40) (3,3,96.90) (4,3,98.50) (5,3,99.80) (6,3,100.00) 
 (1,4,46.80) (2,4,75.30) (3,4,90.00) (4,4,95.30) (5,4,99.40) (6,4,100.00) 
 (1,5,20.00) (2,5,47.90) (3,5,74.00) (4,5,88.60) (5,5,97.70) (6,5,100.00) 
 (1,6,5.70) (2,6,19.40) (3,6,46.80) (4,6,77.90) (5,6,93.20) (6,6,100.00) 
 (1,7,0.50) (2,7,5.10) (3,7,26.00) (4,7,58.90) (5,7,83.10) (6,7,100.00) 
 (1,8,0.10) (2,8,0.50) (3,8,8.60) (4,8,37.00) (5,8,74.20) (6,8,100.00) 
 (1,9,0.00) (2,9,0.10) (3,9,1.50) (4,9,17.10) (5,9,56.50) (6,9,100.00) 
 (1,10,0.00) (2,10,0.00) (3,10,0.10) (4,10,7.00) (5,10,38.80) (6,10,100.00) 
 (1,11,0.00) (2,11,0.00) (3,11,0.00) (4,11,1.40) (5,11,22.00) (6,11,100.00) 
 (1,12,0.00) (2,12,0.00) (3,12,0.00) (4,12,0.00) (5,12,10.40) (6,12,100.00) 
 (1,13,0.00) (2,13,0.00) (3,13,0.00) (4,13,0.00) (5,13,1.70) (6,13,100.00) 
 (1,14,0.00) (2,14,0.00) (3,14,0.00) (4,14,0.00) (5,14,0.50) (6,14,100.00) 
 (1,15,0.00) (2,15,0.00) (3,15,0.00) (4,15,0.00) (5,15,0.00) (6,15,100.00) 
 };
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, welcome to the site! If I understand your question correctly, you just need to make sure to have commas at the right places: There needs to be a comma after `\textsf{100} } }` and after `\textsf{0.6} }` (all keys need to be separated by commas, and `xticklabels={...}` is one key, for instance). Does that address your problem?

Comment: Thanks Jake :)! What a shame I didn't figure that out. :/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about missing commas in key value lists.